# OpenCV show err.message at camera lunch

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, error-handling, raspberry-pi

I would like to lunch a usb-camera at my raspberry pi, but when I try to start python code (opencv), it shows this message and stop a lunch

```
    ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 501
    Aborted
```

Can someone please explain me, what error is this?
It doesnt work even with another codes as well... But camera works fine, when I open it in programs like Camorama webcam viewer. I read that this part makes a problem

```
cv2.waitKey(20)
```

So it makes in another code (when i uncomment it, it lunch the code but dont show camera output) But in this code, even if I uncomment it, the code themself doesn't work: show upper error message

Here is the code

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # HERE 
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: is this the full error code?

Comment: @Rifat Alptekin Çetin Yes, it shows only this

Comment: looks like you some how inputing a key which is not available in ascii

Comment: could it be because I have a japanese keyboard? But it is switched on english characters now... I'm not even pressing any key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh are you Japanese yes bro computers are little racist do not press any japanese letter while your code runing. for waitKey you can use esc or number keys:

```
if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('0'):
    break
```

Comment: thanks for the hint! It works, when I lunch the code from my phone (works remotely from phone, but not pc - probably because of keyboard's "enter" key when I lunch the code)
btw. No, I'm Slovak, but I live in Japan :)